# Decimal Round figure Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etnke.png)I want to round the figure of "Rate" if the decimal value becomes .5 or higher (For Example if 17.57 I want it as 18, if 20.98 I want it as 21)

On the other hand, if the decimal value becomes lower than .5 (For Example if 17.23 I want it as 17, if 20.49 I want it as 20)
I am attaching an image. Please let me know the condition.Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors and data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can use [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function with precision 0.

Answer (score 1):

You just need use Round() function as below:

```
select round(86.54,0) //zero will fix in your case
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `round` function

```
select round('19.6',0)
```

> **Result**

[image]

Comment: Why do you have quotes? It's not text, it's a number

Comment: In Sql server Decimal values should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: That is completely false, [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#decimal-constants)

Comment: apologies and thanks. @Charlieface